Cointegration test FOR loop optimisation in python
I plan to do an experiment in sliding window setting. At each trial I will have a batch of data and I will perform cointegration to select pairs. The issue is that the following function find_cointegrated_pairs(data) takes too long. How can I improve the runtime?
I used following dependencies.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen#
from itertools import combinations
#from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

Tickers from wekipedia
df1 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]
df = yf.download(df1.Symbol.to_list())
df = df["Close"]

The following function performs cointegration test and computes pairs:
def find_cointegrated_pairs(data):
    
    data = data.replace(0,np.nan)
    
    data = pd.DataFrame(data).dropna(axis=1)
    
    #new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index)
    
    combo = []
    
    columns = data.columns
    
    for combination in combinations(columns, 2):
        
        combination_string = combination#"".join(combination)
        
        combo.append(combination_string)
        
        #[combination_string] = data[combination[1]]-data[combination[0]]
    
    #print(data)
    
    #n = data.shape[1]
    
    
    n = len(combo)

    #keys = data.columns.to_list()
    
    keys = combo
    
    #print(keys)
    
    pairs = []
    
    #start = time.time()
    
    for i in range(n):
        
        #for j in range(i+1, n):
            
            #print(data[keys[i]])
            
        df = pd.concat([data[keys[i][0]].diff(),data[keys[i][1]].diff()],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).astype(float)
            
            #print(df)
        df = df.dropna(axis=0)
            
            #print(df)
        
        result = coint_johansen(df,1,k_ar_diff=1)
        
            #print(result)
            
        tracevalues = result.lr1
            
            #print(tracevalues) 
            
        critical_values = result.cvt
        

            
            #print(critical_values[:, 1])
            
        if (tracevalues > critical_values[:, 1]).all():
                
            #model=OLS(data[keys[i][1]].fillna(0).astype(float), data[keys[i][0]].fillna(0).astype(float)).fit()
                
            model=data[[keys[i][1],keys[i][0]]].fillna(0).astype(float).cov()
            
            prams = model.iloc[0,1]/model.iloc[0,0]
            
            #spread = data[keys[i][1]] - model.params.iloc[0] * data[keys[i][0]]
            
            spread = data[keys[i][1]] - prams * data[keys[i][0]]
                
            signal = (spread - spread.mean())/spread.std()
                
            out = pd.concat([pd.Series(keys[i][1]),pd.Series(keys[i][0]),pd.Series(signal.iloc[-1])],axis=1)
                #pairs.append((keys[i], keys[j]))
                
            pairs.append(out)
            
                
    return pd.concat(pairs)

find_cointegrated_pairs(df)


It all depends what you mean by "too long". There are however things you can do. My suggestion here would be to use multiprocessing and adjust depending on the number of CPU:s you have:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen
from itertools import combinations
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time  

df1 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]
df = yf.download(df1.Symbol.to_list())['Close']

def test_cointegration(pair):
    stock1, stock2 = pair
    df_pair = pd.concat([df[stock1].diff(), df[stock2].diff()], axis=1).dropna().astype(float)
    result = coint_johansen(df_pair, det_order=1, k_ar_diff=1)
    trace_stat, crit_value = result.lr1[0], result.cvt[0, 1]
    if trace_stat > crit_value:
        model = df_pair.cov()
        prams = model.iloc[0, 1] / model.iloc[0, 0]
        spread = df[stock2] - prams * df[stock1]
        signal = (spread - spread.mean()) / spread.std()
        return (stock1, stock2, signal.iloc[-1])
    return None

def find_cointegrated_pairs(data):
    start_time = time.time()  
    
    data = data.replace(0, np.nan).dropna(axis=1)
    pairs = list(combinations(data.columns, 2))
    
    with Pool(4) as pool:  
        results = pool.map(test_cointegration, pairs)
    
    results = [result for result in results if result is not None]
    results_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Stock1', 'Stock2', 'Signal'])
    
    end_time = time.time()  
    print(f"Execution Time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")  
    return results_df

cointegrated_pairs = find_cointegrated_pairs(df)
print(cointegrated_pairs)

The execution time (in google.colab) was
Time: 8.072435855865479 seconds

Here, some prices where not found, so the result is
[*********************100%%**********************]  503 of 503 completed
ERROR:yfinance:
2 Failed downloads:
ERROR:yfinance:['BF.B']: Exception('%ticker%: No price data found, symbol may be delisted (1d 1925-05-15 -> 2024-04-21)')
ERROR:yfinance:['BRK.B']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')
[**************************121%%***************************]  609 of 503 completedExecution Time: 8.072435855865479 seconds
    Stock1 Stock2    Signal
0      AEP     BA  1.158257
1      AEP    CAT  5.535086
2      AEP    CNP  0.428345
3      AEP    CVX  2.513893
4      AEP    DIS  1.884417
..     ...    ...       ...
271    MRO     PG  2.936003
272    MRO    XOM  2.657470
273    MSI     PG  2.543588
274    MSI    XOM  2.051337
275     PG    XOM  2.120708

[276 rows x 3 columns]

